# My tab controller is not visible in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabcontroller

I'm new at iOS programming and I'm try to add a tab controller to a certain UIViewController. I embedded the View Controller with a tab controller using the relationship View Controller. Then I added a second view controller and added the relationship view controller to link it to the tab controller to create the second tab. However when I go to the app, the tabs are not visible. It's weird cause I feel like what I did makes sense.

[image]

Comment: Which view controller does your app start on? I don't see the starting arrow anywhere.

Comment: It starts on ViewController. Sorry I couldn't capture the whole storyboard. Anyway i got it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little mistake: your `RegisterViewController` should have a segue to the `TabBarController`, instead of directly to the `MainViewController`.

Comment: Yep. I figured it out and I was about to write the answer down. You beat me to it :)